# Can I persuade stack / ghci to *only* load the local .ghci file?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghci

I have a `.ghci` in my local project directory, and another one in my `$HOME`. When I do a `stack ghci`, then `$HOME/.ghci` is loaded first, followed by `$PWD/.ghci`. Is it possible to have ONLY the local .ghci be loaded, and the global one ignored?

I could do a `stack exec -- ghci -ignore-dot-ghci`, but then, none is loaded.

What I also tried is:

```
stack exec -- ghci -ignore-dot-ghci -W .ghci
```

The idea being to first tell ghci not to load anything and then explicitly requesting the local .ghci file, but this gives the error message *Warning: ignoring unrecognised input `.ghci'*

Comment: It seems invoking `stack ghci` from within the project directory should load the local version first (`./.ghci`) and then the global one (`~/.ghci`) but i think there is no way around making stack ignore one of them. However is there a need for this? The global one should have general settings such as the prompt, `:set +s` and some colors perhaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GHCi has [a `-ghci-script` flag](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghc-flag--ghci-script) which can be used alongside `-ignore-dot-ghci`. It can be used with `stack ghci` through `--ghci-options`:

```
stack ghci --ghci-options "-ignore-dot-ghci -ghci-script .ghci"
```

For the sake of completeness, here is the corresponding `cabal repl` invocation:

```
cabal repl --repl-options "-ignore-dot-ghci" --repl-options "-ghci-script .ghci"
```